# Receber dados json mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Olá, tenho a seguinte função para ler dados do BD mysql.

Aqui eu chamo ->

```
$clientes = DBRead('clientes', null, 'nome, telefone1');
```

Aqui eu exibo ->

```
echo $nam = json_encode($clientes);
```

Resultado:

```
[
  {
    "nome":"Davi",
    "telefone1":"654654"
  },
  {
    "nome":"Davi",
    "telefone1":null
  },
  {
    "nome":"Davi",
    "telefone1":null
  }
]
```

Aqui tento manipular os resultados separadamente:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($nam);

    $dados = $jsonObj->nome;

    foreach ( $dados as $e ) { echo "nome: $e->nome "; }
```

mas da o seguinte erro

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Já tentei colocar ", true" apos o decode mas não funcionou.

Alguém tem uma idéia de como eu posso tratar esses dados?

Aqui a Função de busca em outro arquivo->

```
    function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table = $table;
    $params = ($params) ?" {$params}" : null;
$query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
$result = DBExecute($query);
if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
    return false;
else{
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $res;
    }
    return $data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

este código não vai funcionar mesmo, porque `$dados` não é um objeto, `$jsonObj` é que é. Faça assim que dá certo:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($nam);

    foreach ( $jsonObj as $e ) { echo "nome: $e->nome "; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Muito Obrigado a Todos, graças a ajuda consegui resolver da seguinte maneira.

```
 $clientes = DBRead('clientes', null, '*');
  $nam = json_encode($clientes);
  $res = json_decode($nam, true);
  foreach ( $res as $e ) 
      { echo $e['nome']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($nam);
foreach ( $jsonObj as $e ) { 
echo "nome: $e->nome - telefone: $e->telefone1<br />"; 
}
```